# Reading outlook email with a specific from address in python with POP3

Tags: python, pop3, outlook.com

```
import getpass, poplib
user = 'my_user_name' 
Mailbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop-mail.outlook.com.com', '995') 
Mailbox.user(user) 
Mailbox.pass_('my_password') 
numMessages = len(Mailbox.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    for msg in Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print msg
Mailbox.quit()
```

The above code is from python POP3 docs, I used that and it worked. But, that is not what actually I want. I want to read emails those came only from a specific from address. I didn't find any methods in python POP3 library. Can anyone help?

Comment: POP3 has no filter/search abilities. You have to look through the emails yourself.

Comment: ohh... what about IMAP? does that have?

Answer (score 1):

The POP3 protocol only allows to:

- get the number of messages
- retrieve a full message
- delete a message

An optional command (TOP msg n) allows to read only the n first lines of a message. In theory, you could use it to only fully download messages coming from a specific address. This command is supported by the poplib module, but the manual says:

> ...unfortunately, TOP is poorly specified in the RFCs and is frequently broken in off-brand servers. Test this method by hand against the POP3 servers you will use before trusting it.

My advice is *do not even try to use that*, it is likely to break sooner or later. If you must stick with POP3 do what mail readers do: download everything and filter it client side. And if you really want to filter the messages server side, forget the POP3 protocol and use IMAP4 that is aimed at it. It has a nice support in Python through the `imaplib` module